# Manage file deletion in PHP

Tags: apache2, php, delete, websites

I am creating a PHP website where you upload 2 images, and it combines them, then lets you download the final product. Currently I have it set up to create a UserID that is stored in cookies. Then all files from that userID are stored in a custom folder in `/user/UserID`. How do I automatically delete the files from that folder after 2 hours, and the folder itself, if it is empty?

I have done some searching, but I can't seem to find a easy way to delete files after 2 hours, since the user may not be on the page anymore, so I can't execute it from inside the PHP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a file like this sample:

```
$myFile = "testFolder/sampleDeleteFile.txt";
unlink($myFile) or die("Couldn't delete file");
```

With the function `sleep()` you can wait 2h (7200000ms) after deleting the files and restart each time if the user visits the site again within these 2 hours.

I hope this will helps you. Otherwise you must post your code for specific changes...

Comment: ok, thank you. will this keep running for two hours after the user leaves the page, or will it  stop the second they leave?

Comment: depends on how you program it, `sleep()` is just a function where time counts down in ms... look at [PHP setcookie() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_http_setcookie)

Comment: or you simply use your script in a cronjib which is set to two hours